# I cannot create android project in Android Studio, why?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: AndroidStudio]

I downloaded and installed Android Studio. But I cannot create or open android project. There isn't Android in New Project Tab. Why? How can I create and open Android project in Android Studio?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885257/cant-create-android-studio-project-in-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885257/cant-create-android-studio-project-in-android-studio) answer is in above link

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885257/cant-create-android-studio-project-in-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885257/cant-create-android-studio-project-in-android-studio) Answer is in above link

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to download the Android SDK to use along with Android Studio. Android Studio is just the IDE of IntelliJ IDEA, but without the Android libraries. See [this link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) for installation.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GarBtHK.png--> There was sdk from AndroidStudio installation and I installed new sdk. However, i am not creating Android Project

Comment: You're going to want to set the directory of the SDK in your settings for Android Studio.

Comment: There aren't any setting for Android in AndroidStudio

Comment: In the main menu, look in Configurations -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure and there is a field for Android SDK location.

Answer (score 2):

You should add "Android Support" in "Setting -> Plugins" .

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391203/i-cannot-create-android-project-in-android-studio-why).