# can't create android studio project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Few days ago I have received an update patch(I don't remember what for were that update it was 5 MB of size), after installing it, studio somehow crashed and stopped working, when I'm starting it there is not wizard for creating android project. I tried to uninstall every file of android studio then download fresh download pack, install it but same problem. (OS Ubuntu 16.04)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason Plugin for Android is disabled or removed/corrupt

From your Home Screen of your Android Studio

Configure -> Plugins -> Enable Plugin for Android

Then Ok, and Restart

Comment: thanks, first problem fixed, now when I'm opening the project during indexing it says Error:Cause: invalid stream header: 823267D1

Comment: this is happening if I'll create new project

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464473/errorcause-invalid-stream-header-000900d9-in-android-studio-2-3-1

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the Android Studio file corrupted file problem.

Close your Android Studio then Delete .AndroidStudio directory from the Users directory and start Android Studio Again is works for me.

```
C:\Users\[use_name]\\.AndroidStudio
```