# Android Studio, Create new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know if I changed something without realizing it but I keep getting a different window when I try to create a new project.

Do I need to reset Android Studio, if so how do I do that, or is there any way for me to fix this or at least how to get around it?

[image]

Comment: What is your first window? Could you create a screenshot from that one too?

Comment: I can't find any place where I add pictures.

Comment: A link of the picture is also good, put it on imgur for example. By the way the screen you are facing with is not familiar to me at all, that's why that picture would be great.

Comment: is it fine if I share a gdrive link of the picture?

Comment: Yes, it will be okay.

Comment: Flip, imgur and gdrive are blocked on the network that I'm using, soon as I can find a way to share I'll out a link here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVQugmKikUvX3FvRWtwSy0yVm8/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to file => setting => plugins => android support plugins enable

Comment: I can go to file then project structure, but I can't "enable android support plugin" anywhere, where do I look?

Comment: go to file => setting => plugins => android support plugins enable.

Comment: Cannot Save Settings:
Unable to apply changes: plugins "Apps Link Assistant", "Firebase Services" won't be able to load
I'm getting this message..

Comment: do all the plugin enable and which android studio version u used?

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like you have installed Android Studio IDE, but **Android SDK is missing** - that's what could help you to create a new Android Application project. [There is a discussion about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391219/5596869). Hope it can help you! ;)